# Windows Environment Variable in Connection String

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

How do you use an environment variable in an Excel sheet connection string, getting the error, ODBC Excel Driver Login Failed ... is not a valid path

Comment: You should provide more detail, in general `"aaa=" & environ$("VAR_NAME") & ";bbb`

Comment: @AlexK. can I place an environment variable in the connection string itself without changing the connection string with vba every single time? for example DBQ=%myenvironmentvariable%;

Answer (score 0):

If the provider errors then its not expanding the strings and you will need to do it manually, running the string through a function before assigning.

In a module:

```
Private Declare Function ExpandEnvironmentStrings Lib "kernel32" Alias "ExpandEnvironmentStringsA" (ByVal lpSrc As String, ByVal lpDst As String, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

Public Function ExpandEnv(str As String) As String
    Dim size As Long
    size = ExpandEnvironmentStrings(str, ExpandEnv, size)
    ExpandEnv = Space$(size)
    size = ExpandEnvironmentStrings(str, ExpandEnv, size)
    ExpandEnv = Left$(ExpandEnv, size - 1)
End Function
```

For

```
?ExpandEnv("aaa %temp% bbb %username% ccc") 
aaa C:\NULL bbb AlexK ccc
```